# Override the bootstrap 5.2

Tags: html, css

I have a project built with *bootstrap 3.3*, I wanted to re-create it using the latest *bootstrap 5.2*.

The problem is that the `.container` is not the same and their functions.

For example:

In *Bootstrap 3.3*
[image: Centered Container]

Explanation: The container still centered even the viewing is too small, and all child elements still in contact and only got smaller. **That's what im trying to do in bootstrap 5.2**

In *Bootstrap 5.2*
[image: Overflowed Container]
Explanation: The Container got overflowed after I **override** the *bootstrap 5.2* with the *bootstrap 3.3* properties. Here's what it looks like:

```css
@media (min-width: 280px) {
        .container {
            width: 750px;
            max-width: none;
        }

        .container1 {
            width: 750px;
            max-width: none;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
            width: 1170px;
            max-width: none;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .container {
            width: 970px;
            max-width: none;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container {
            width: 1170px;
            max-width: none;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 280px) {
        .col-sm-6 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 280px) {
        .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9 {
            float: left;
        }
    }

    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
```

Is there any other way to do this without any conflicts?

Comment: Don't overwrite the container and cols like that. Use SCSS to adapt sizes of containers.

Comment: @syfy this is definitely the wrong way to do so. Overriding the grid system of the Bootstrap with old version will crash the whole grid system. Since Bootstrap v4 is a major rewrite of the framework, you probably need to rewrite everything when you update to v5 [Migration guide to v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/) and [v4 to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/)

Comment: So the last option is to use SCSS? I can blend the css with scss?

Comment: Just rewrite the whole structure. The whole concept has changed since v3 to v5.

Comment: Don't know what you mean `blend CSS with SCSS` SCSS will in the end be compiled to CSS, do you mean if you can blend the CSS with CSS? But just have a look on how bootstrap really works, with scss you can set variables for bootstrap to define container-size, columns and much more.